# How do I remove Pages from search?

Tags: search

I don't need to search for pages in my site and only want to search posts, is there a way to do it?  Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The below should make the page post type no longer search-able.

```
function remove_pages_from_search() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $wp_post_types['page']->exclude_from_search = true;
}
add_action('init', 'remove_pages_from_search');
```

Comment: Where do I place that code? Thanks

Comment: You can place it in functions.php of your theme.

Comment: Thanks an awful lot. I just copy pasted it and it works perfectly

Comment: Is there any way to hide specific pages instated of all the pages?

Comment: This idea doesn't follow WP API and as any direct vars modification should be considered as hack rather than as solution.

Answer (score 14):

The following in functions.php also works well:

```
//Remove pages from search results
function mySearchFilter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'post');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
```

Comment: shuold be the sollution. more elegant, more maintainable. hte above just modifies post type params, this one the search query itself. +1

Comment: Modifying the post type object for the 'page' post type is a better solution.  This solution forces the post type to be hard set as 'post' for all search queries which would keep any custom post types from showing up in the search if a site had any.  Globally setting the exclude_from_search property of the 'page' post type object means that any code that depends on checking this property will have the correct information.

Comment: Somewhat relevant link with a little more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types_in_the_main_Query

Comment: Works well but not shoing topic in bbpress, so it is not good.
Using "$wp_post_types['page']->exclude_from_search = true;" is a good options seems

Answer (score 3):

Here is code for removing specific pages from search in WordPress, add the following code in a function.php file
Just replace the array with your page ID's

```
function remove_pages_from_search($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post__not_in', array(3031,2958,2926));
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','remove_pages_from_search');
```

Comment: It's working for me. Thank you and upvote from my side

Answer (score 1):

put this in your search.php

`<?php if (is_search() && ($post->post_type=='page')) continue; ?>`

right below this code -> `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>`

you can find more on here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-search-only-posts-exclude-pages

Comment: I don't have a search.php if I retrieve one from another theme will it work? Thanks

Comment: yes. first create a blank search.php then copy and paste the code from index.php. then do what i told you above.

Comment: actually you should use @prettyboymp's code. its easier and does what you asked. i tested it. if you want..

Answer (score 1):

This solution follows (respects) WP API rather than modifying internal vars directly.

Notice that this way you can also include (overwrite registration) types or change registration arguments provided in [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/). Check out [`'exclude_from_search'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#exclude_from_search) description in docs.

```php
/**
 * Filter object types in search results.
 * 
 * @param array $args  Array of arguments for registering a post type.
 *                     See the register_post_type() function for accepted arguments.
 * @param string $type Post (object) type key (e.g. 'post', 'page', 'attachment'...,
 *                     or any custom post type registered).
 * @return array Filtered type attributes.
 */
function _filter_search_types( $args, $type ) {
    $exclude_types = array( 'page' );

    if ( in_array( $type, $exclude_types, true ) ) {
        $args['exclude_from_search'] = true;
    }

    return $args;
}
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', __NAMESPACE__ . '\_filter_search_types', 10, 2 );
}
```

Comment: @Rup - I said about WP API, not WP REST API (which is irrelevant here). And this is not "alternative way" of the accepted answer but "the right way", since "accepted answer" doesn't follow WP API and as any direct vars modification should be considered as hack rather than as a solution.

Comment: @Rup - And you're right - `comment` isn't a post type (corrected).

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood, sorry